# Addition between Integer and Float.... resulting in a Zero

Tags: c++, linux, math, timespec

I have been doing an operation in C++ on the timer struct of Linux provided by the interface ***"clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &CurrentTime)"***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec CurrentTime;
    CurrentTime.tv_sec = 28220;
    CurrentTime.tv_nsec = 461189000;

    unsigned long long TimeNow;
    TimeNow = (28220 * 1000000) + (461189000 * 0.001);

    std::cout << TimeNow;
}
```

yet the result always giving ***TimeNow*** as a Zero.

I would appreciate if any has answer to this question or a lead to follow.
It was done using GCC Compiler

Code Snipped could be found here 
http://rextester.com/XRR83683

Comment: Instead of sprinkling bits of C++ code throughout the question, how about providing a single [mcve]?

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/XSP25641)

Comment: Thank you Igor, Try replacing the value instead of the variables, it would result to 0   http://rextester.com/XRR83683

Comment: Please edit your post. Put the code there and format it properly. Neither the speach-code mix in your post nor the poorly formatted code in your comment are readable.

Comment: Kindly Find the code here http://rextester.com/XRR83683

Comment: What part of "edit your post and put the code there" you don't understand?

Comment: `(28220 * 1000000)` is an `int` multiplied by an `int`, and likely overflows.

Comment: @AhmedYzab I'm downvoting due to no research.  What's so difficult in printing out the intermediate results, thus focusing on what the problem is?  [Here is your code with those simple tests I put in](http://rextester.com/LPSOBR20168).  Then the initial question from you should have been a simple "why when I multiply these two numbers, I get the wrong answer?".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Thank you for your comments, if you may excuse me but I still do not understand how the calculation yields to 0. I have done these checks and cannot understand why starting from having the value 27918 for the CurrentTime.tv_sec, the calculation yields to 0.

Comment: in `(28220 * 1000000) + (461189000 * 0.001)`, `(28220 * 1000000)` is calculated with `int` types, and overflows... and `(461189000 * 0.001)` is calculated with `double`s and added to it, yielding a `double`.  Then that wildly incorrect `double` value is converted to `unsigned long long` for assignment to `TimeNow`.  Try using `28220LL` instead of `28220` and you'll get a reasonable answer.

Comment: I have edited the question showing that the problem is the overflow just as @Dmitri suggested (he should turn his comments into an answer...).  I think the edit shows what is actually being asked but if the edit isn't helpful please roll it back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again, My objective is not to correct it, but actually to understand what is happenning exactly and being able to do it with handwriting calculations:
I have done what you have described on hand and doesnt yield to 0
(28220 * 1000000) = (2450196224) "after the truncation for int", The Double calculation produces (461189).

adding them together in double yields to "2450657413" which is in hex 92121085.
So i don't understand, is the double value casted to the unsigned long long, is it an implicit truncation of the IEEE double to the 64bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
TimeNow = (28220 * 1000000) + (461189000 * 0.001);
```

the `(28220 * 1000000)` part is calculated using `int`s, and (with 32-bit `int`) overflows giving an incorrect value (likely -1844771072).

The `(461189000 * 0.001)` part is calculated using `double`s, because of the `0.001` double constant, giving 461189.0 as a `double`.

The two are then added together, giving a negative `double` value... when that negative `double` is converted to `unsigned long long` for the assignment to `TimeNow`, it's being converted as 0, probably because that's the closest value in its range to any negative number.  This is different from converting a negative integer type to unsigned, which would "wrap around".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really makes sense to me now (At the end the question is not trivial, lots of people who do not have clear answer down-voted it :) ) But your answer takes me to the second part of the question, Why it works fine with variables as shown [link](http://rextester.com/EIUEQ62755)here

Comment: @AhmedYzab that's because on that implementation, `time_t` (which is the type of `CurrentTime.tv_sec`) is wider than 32-bit so the multiplication is also performed in the wider type and doesn't overflow.